# Integrating xamarin, CouchBaseLite, MVVMCross and SyncGateway such that View changes with database

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am working on a xamarin project where i use CouchBase Lite as my Local database. I also want to use MVVMCross library. Could anyone specify where should i include couchbase-Lite library, MVVMCross - hot tuna library(like class library or portable class library or platform specif project) such that view model gets notified about the changes in Couchdatabase.

Basically i want to change the view whenver there is a change in database i want to change the view with mvvmcross. Am using syncgateway to sync with server Couchbase bucket.

I am new to Xamarin, MVVM and CouchBaselite. 
I couldnt find any concrete example for all this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQLite is best for mobile apps.  Xamarin provides more samples using SQLite DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would perhaps just use the [CouchBaseLite Xamarin Component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/couchbase-lite-net).  If you are wanting to access this in your PCL Core project you will probably have to create some sort of wrapper around the component and inject it properly into each platform.  You can use the [MvvmCross plugins](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins) wiki to get you started.

Comment: Now i have added the Couchbaselite component to the Xamarin.Android Project. In grocery-sync example they have used TinyIoc to access the CouchBase service which is written in Shared.Back and they resolve it in Shared.Front and Native project. My question is how to do the same with MVVMCross and PCL. From PCL what kind of wrapper and how to inject that dependency into viewmodel. Because in MVVMCross viewmodel will be in PCL project only.

Comment: There is really a lot more work on your end that you need to do to understand how MvvmCross and the plugin model works.  I highly recommend [Stuart's N+1](http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com/) series to get yourself familiarized with how it works.  At this point you are really asking us to do your work for you.  If you come back with specific coding issues we'd be happy to help but unfortunately this requires some more leg work on your end.

Comment: As for your specific IoC question you have a couple options.  MvvmCross has it's own IoC framework... i.e. var plugin = Mvx.Resolve<Myplugin>() or you can find out how to swap out MvvmCross's IoC framework with Tiny IoC [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control).

Comment: yeah i get it. Sorry for asking an abstract question. I tried it and its almost working. Once i get it fully i will post it here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but there's a new MvvmCross plugin for Couchbase, and basically does everything you want.  It's in alpha, as of this writing on Nuget, and open source on Github.  I was actually looking for the same, and happy to have found it!   :)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvX.Plugins.CouchBaseLite.ForestDB

https://github.com/mathieumack/MvvX.CouchBaseLite